# Rails: multiple layouts with similar code and structure - DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, layout, dry

The view code below is a bit verbose, so let me state my problem and question first. I have multiple layouts with somewhat slightly different code in each one. Currently, I've tried to limit any redundancy through the use of partials. However, I still wonder if it could be more DRY. Obviously, it's one of the core principles to keep things as DRY as possible, but I wonder how much effort it's worth in some cases where just being consistent (if even it's not DRY) still gives you the efficiency and maintainability that you need. So, given that, what would you recommend? Btw, my environment is Rails 2.3.12.

```
# LAYOUT #1

<%= render :partial => 'shared/html_header' %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <%= render :partial => "shared/head" %>           
  <body>
    <%= render :partial => "shared/announcements" %>       
    <div id="outer">
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/banner' %>
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/nav' %>
      <div id="main">          
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= render :partial => 'shared/content' %>
            </td>
            <td><%= spacer_img(:width => 10) %></td>
            <td>
              <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_a', :locals => {:box_color => 'greenBox'}) %>
              <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_b', :locals => {:box_color => 'blueBox'}) %>
              <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_c', :locals => {:box_color => 'redBox'}) %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/footer' %>
    </div>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/google_analytics_script' %>
  </body>
</html>

# LAYOUT #2

<%= render :partial => 'shared/html_header' %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <%= render :partial => "shared/head" %>
<body>
  <%= render :partial => "shared/announcements" %>
  <div id="outer">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/banner' %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/nav' %>
    <div id="main">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= render :partial => 'shared/enticement_rendering' %>
            <%= render :partial => 'shared/content' %>
          </td>
          <td><%= spacer_img(:width => 5) %></td>
          <td>
            <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_x', :locals => {:box_color => 'greenBox'}) %>
            <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_y', :locals => {:box_color => 'blueBox'}) %>
            <%= render(:partial => 'shared/sidebar_z', :locals => {:box_color => 'redBox'}) %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/footer' %>
  </div>
    <%= update_lb_javascript %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/google_analytics_script' %>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the only thing that changes is the sidebar boxes, is this correct?

Easiest solution would be to come up with a configuration that gets set in the controller and just use one view file..

So in one action:

```
@sidebars = [ {:name => 'sidebar_a', :color => 'blue'}, {:name => 'sidebar_b', :color => green} ]
```

In another:

```
@sidebars = [ {:name => 'sidebar_c', :color => 'blue'}, {:name => 'sidebar_d', :color => green} ]
```

And then your view becomes:

```
<% @sidebars.each do |sidebar| %>
  <%= render(:partial => "shared/#{sidebar.name}", :locals => {:box_color => sidebar.color}) %>
<% end %>
```